# How to profile swap space with JConsole

Tags: java, memory-management, solaris, swap

I've got a Java web app (WAR) deployed to Tomcat on a remote Solaris machine that is throwing IOExceptions claiming "Not enough space". After spending several days painfully researching the issue, I see that I have some process forking going on in my code that requires Solaris to place both parent/child processes in the system swap space, and every now and again there is not enough swap space to contain both processes. [Here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/IOException+Not+enough+space) is an article that explains what is happening more eloquently/intelligently than I can. But its definitely the culprit.

So I need to put in a ticket with our systems admin to increase swap space, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how much space I need. I can use JConsole to profile memory usage on the server, but on the `VM Summary` tab the swap space used/available info seems to only get read when JConsole starts up and does not refresh. This prevents me from using JConsole to see real-time swap usage while I reproduce this forking/memory issue.

The only server monitor I have access to is something called `prstat` (I'm used to `top` and `nmon`).

I need to give systems a specific number (ie. *Please increase myserver.net's swap space by 250M*, etc.). **How can I obtain this number?** The server is running on Java 1.6u25 so maybe there are some Java tools I'm not aware of, or perhaps some Solaris profilers/monitors I might be able to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you provide more information like the current RAM and swap size, the number of JVMs running, their heap size and virtual memory usage and the expected level of concurrency of these forking processes. `prstat -Z` output would also help.

In any case, you can monitor you virtual memory usage with the `swap -s` command and make sure the last value (...k available) is always large enough.

Note that despite a common belief, there is no problem at all having too large a swap so I would suggest simply doubling you current swap area size as a first approach.

You got the current swap area size with the `swap -l` command.

[Here](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/solaris_memory.html) is an article about Solaris application memory management that might also help.

Answer (score 1):

Often you would make the swap space at least as big as the main memory size. So a 16 GB machine might have 16 GB of swap. (It used to be the case that the swap was many times the main memory size)

For Java, apart from "off-heap" memory it all has to be in physcial memory. This is because if you do a GC for example, it will examine all the memory and if even some of this has been swapped your application will hang for seconds or minutes at a time.

If your application appears to need more swap space its highly likely that what you really need is more main memory.

Comment: Thanks @Peter - what are your thoughts on the article I referenced? Thats straight from the Hudson team and they clearly specify swap space/VM being the issue...

Comment: A lack of swap will cause the error. If you have lots of idle processes running, increasing the swap is all you need do. More likely you really need most of you programs in memory and increasing the swap will just make the error go way, but your real problem is a lack of main memory.

Comment: Yes but @Peter you have simply reinforced my question! I already know swap space is an issue - I'm asking how to determine (using the tools/platform I'm limited to) how much swap I need to add! And I'm not in a position to trial different amounts because I need to put the request into a ticket and systems frowns upon lots of similar "tweak"-type requests - I need to perform the calculation once and get it right!

Comment: The only way to know is to make it larger than what you need and see how much you didn't use.  Once you have this error you cannot deternmine how much swap would have been used. It like trying to determine what to increase your maximum memory to if you get an OOME. If they frown on interative tweaking, they should give you a test machine which is the same as production which you can work out what it should be.

Comment: But as I keep saying, increasing swap space is unlikely to help anyway.

Comment: I just got off the phone with a manager in systems and they said that setting up a test server to mirror prod was not feasible or in the budget.

Comment: In which case they can't expect you to know how much memory it would have used if it could. One way around this to to ask for a significant increase in swap space which you can be confident is more than needed. A system shouldn't be running close to its limit in swap space anyway.